# do-release-upgrade fails on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, do-release-upgrade

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on a virtual host. I've tried upgrading to a newer version by running `do-release-upgrade` but the process fails with the following error(s).

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                    

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                    

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                                                                                                                                                           

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                                                    

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                                                                                     

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                    

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                    

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                    

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                                                                                                                                                           
  404  Not Found                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                                                    
  404  Not Found                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                                                                                     
  404  Not Found                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                    

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                    

Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                    
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Failed to fetch 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources 
404 Not Found 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages 
404 Not Found 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages 
404 Not Found 
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or 
old ones used instead. 

Restoring original system state
```

Comment: You have a PPA configured which isn't active anymore. Remove the `ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto` ppa from "Software sources". Then try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the ppa and update:

```
sudo sudo add-apt-repository --remove ferramroberto/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: `ppa-purge` is not a regular system provided package, as far as I know. I think you should include how to install `ppa-purge`.

Comment: fixed it for you